# Wordpress - List posts of a custom post type from sub-categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called my-plays, within which I've created the categories short-plays and long-plays. I would like to just be able to output a list of the posts in each category... at the moment I can only find code which just outputs a lists of all posts in my-plays. Is it possible to list posts in a category of a custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879904/getting-posts-from-categories-array).

```
<?php

$args = array
(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'category'    => array(48,43,49,46,47,44,51,50,42),
    'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
query_posts($args);

?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This didn't completely work... if I put the post_type as "my-plays", then it does list all of the posts of that custom post type, but entering my categories IDs (or "tag_IDs" as they now are) doesn't filter it from there, it just keeps listing all of them.